# rospack can't find package created with catkin_create_package

Tags: ros, catkin-create-pkg, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working through the beginner tutorials using ROS Hydro and I attempted to create my first package by running:

```
$ catkin_create_pkg beginner_tutorials std_msgs rospy roscpp
```

This produced no errors and appears to have created the associated files and folders.  However, using rospack to find the newly created package doesn't work:

```
$ rospack find beginner_tutorials 
[rospack] Error: stack/package beginner_tutorials not found
```

What am I missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/99551/rospack-can%27t-find-package-created-with-catkin_create_package/) by [altemir](https://answers.ros.org/users/7486/altemir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2013-11-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you create the package in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH? Try also to run 'rospack profile' before running the rospack find command.

---

Originally posted by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) with karma: 808 on 2013-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2019-09-27**:
What do you mean by " did you create the package in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH"?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ros sometime does not recognise newly created packages.

Solution:
go to 
source devel/setup.bash

close terminal and open new terminal. Now you would be able to find that package.

---

Originally posted by [tonyParker](https://answers.ros.org/users/15131/tonyparker/) with karma: 377 on 2017-10-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-10-05**:
Closing terminal after sourcing is pointless because the source will be lost. @Tirjen is right, `rospack profile` should do the work if the package is already sourced.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a similar problem with a package i created using the catkin_create_pkg tool. here's what i did:

1. erase all the folders and files in your catkin_ws except "src"
2. build your catkin_ws (catkin_make or catkin build whatever you use)
3. go to ~/catkin_ws/devel and find your setup.bash file (the point is to just make sure you know the path to this file)
4. go to your home folder, ctr+h to see hidden files, open the .bashrc file and at the end add "source [path to the setup file from step 3]
5. close your terminal, open it again and now your packages in the catkin_ws/src should be registered.

hope i helped somebody

---

Originally posted by [BlackBirdLab](https://answers.ros.org/users/38041/blackbirdlab/) with karma: 21 on 2018-10-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bld-abir](https://answers.ros.org/users/44862/bld-abir/) on 2019-08-15**:
thanks a lot...
It worked for me... !!
Is it necessary to always put the path as a source in the .bashrc ? for each package i'll create